# В чем ошибка? file_get_contents()

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php7

При попытке отправить запрос:

```
file_get_contents($api.$access_token . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message));
```

Файл перекодируется и образуется строка:

```
file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot12..../sendMessage?chat_id=88....6&amp;amp;text=8366)
```

Почему так происходит? Как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: как вы это поняли?